# How to add required styles to text with specific fonts?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want all text on my site with the font name 'classylight' to have a letter spacing and word spacing of 50px each.

Defining a class in the site map and adding class names for each post is a time consuming process.

To reduce the time, I tried to solve this issue with the `attribute*=style` property.

I tried -

```
body ["style=font-family:classylight"] {
letter-spacing:50px;
word-spacing:50px; 
}
```

It's not working. Can anyone help? I would prefer css for this. If there's no possibility in css, please refer with javascript, jquery.

PS - I'm not looking for answers which adds styles directly to body part like

```
p {
font-family: classylight;
letter-spacing:50px;
word-spacing:-20px; 
}
<p>text</p>
```

Or

```
.classylight {
   font-family: classylight;
    letter-spacing:50px;
    word-spacing:-20px;
}
<p class="classylight">text</p>
```

These are time consuming as I use different fonts for different lines for different paras for different posts!!!

Comment: What is your problem with the classes? Attribute selector is much slower than the class selector.

Comment: To use an attribute selector you would have to ensure that the font-family is set in an inline style rather than via a stylesheet using a class. I echo @Teemu's question which does seem the better way to do it.

Comment: If you'd show a use-case of the HTML that contains the "lines", "paras" and "posts", and explained what CSS you want to apply to each element, we migh find a "non-time-consuming" solution to your problem.

Comment: cuz im a little lazy and bit boozy.

Comment: @Teemu, I said these were time consuming cuz both letter and word spacing, unlike other font styles, would inherit properties to child so i have to again set the values to initial for the childs everytime

Comment: Just give that example. You're consuming time here much more than creating a proper code would take ...

Comment: @Teemu, You are more concerned about the code which is unneccessary in this case, and you are more interested in pointing down issues rather than answering the way.

Comment: @Kraken
Using JavaScript: 
`var alleles = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0, max=alleles.length; i < max; i++) {
    font = getComputedStyle(alleles[i]).getPropertyValue("font-family");
    if(font=="classylight"){
        i.style.letterSpacing = 50 + "px";
        i.style.wordSpacing = 10 + "px";
    }
}`
Would this work?

Comment: Actually I _was_ interested in resolving the problem with CSS, but never mind ...

Comment: @Teemu Oh, LOL. Wait...does that mean my code works?

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder No, it means that I'm not interested to resolve OP's issue anymore. I don't know whether your code works or not, because I can't see the HTML with which the code should work. But the issue could probably be resolved with a couple of complex selectors and OP could get rid of the stupid inline style and that selector, it's much faster to write a single short class name than that inline style attribute ...

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder your code *probably* works - now if only OP had provided an example of their HTML to test it on...

Answer (score 0):

if you have own fonts.css then u can directly add css letter-spacing:50px;
word-spacing:50px; on your font css file

Answer (score 0):

Try this and add reference of the css file in your main html page.

```
body  {
letter-spacing:50px;
word-spacing:50px; 
font-family:classylight;
}
```